# Is Local Cache works with Co-Located Cache

Tags: azure

I am using the Azure Co-Located Cache.Can I enable the **local cache** for **Co-Located cache** and if I enable how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Co-located cache does not remove its distributed nature, so yes you should be able to enable local cache on a co-located cluster. On a single node colo cache, this wouldn't make sense as even with a local cache no network hop would be saved.

In local cache the client itself maintains a local copy of recently cached objects. As with any cache solution, you need to see what degree of staleness of data you can swallow and how to invalidate your data. (use notifications etc.)